# Why are some software packages so big?

Tags: files, packages

Some packages that I install – which I assume contain nothing but code – are tens or even hundreds of MB. For example, I recently installed [pytorch](https://pytorch.org/) and the size of the binary was 428 MB.

How can there possible be that much code?

Comment: Open it up and see? I don't know what to tell you beyond that. You downloaded it, you can inspect it yourself. At a guess, for pytorch, i would say it's probably from packaged dependencies.

Comment: I'm more wondering in general how packages can be _so_ large. This is obviously not all code.

Comment: Binaries are generally going to be bigger than compiled code. The one example you gave, I answered below.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's probably due to large .SO files that support multiple GPU architectures. If you want to skinny down the size, you could compile it yourself. https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/15591